# Complex CSS/LESS: Why doesn't this nth-child(even) ~ p work?

Tags: html, css, less, frontend

I'm trying to make an alternating pattern using nth-child(even), where even elements and it's respective general siblings are red.

However, after trying for a while, I cannot figure out how to make a "general sibling selector" to be the same color as the element that is alternating colors....

Here's a snippet:

```css
h1:nth-child(even),
h1:nth-child(even) ~ p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Section 1</h1>
<p>I am odd.</p>
<p>I am odd.</p>

    
<h1>Section 2</h1>
<p>I am even and I should be red.</p>
<p>I am even and I should be red.</p>

<h1>Section 1</h1>
<p>I am odd.</p>
<p>I am odd.</p>
    
<h1>Section 2</h1>
<p>I am even and I should be red.</p>
<p>I am even and I should be red.</p>
```

Also, here's an example in jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/tixobu/edit?html,css,output

Is this even possible? Any help or tidbits would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need [Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)  not [General sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

```css
h1:nth-child(even),
h1:nth-child(even) + p, h1:nth-child(even) + p + p{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Section 1</h1>
<p>I am odd.</p>
<p>I am odd.</p>

    
<h1>Section 2</h1>
<p>I am even and I should be red.</p>
<p>I am even and I should be red.</p>

<h1>Section 1</h1>
<p>I am odd.</p>
<p>I am odd.</p>
    
<h1>Section 2</h1>
<p>I am even and I should be red.</p>
<p>I am even and I should be red.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That definitely works in this case, but what if  there are variable number of <p> tags?

Comment: You could wrap your `p`aragraphs in a `div` and use `h1:nth-child(even) + div` instead.

Comment: as @Jonathon said the best way would be wrapping them in divs or jou can just use JS.

Comment: Sweet...that's it! Thanks all!!